# jQuery Stop submitting form by checking error variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events

I have a simple form with some form fields. Some of them are required some are not. The required field are required by adding the class 'required'.

When I submit I check the `#contact-form` fields and on the basis of there I give the empty field error classes and submit the form yes or no.

Adding the error classes to the fields is not a problem, but checking the "error" variable is. Because I don't know where I can check the error variable.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function (event) {
    var errors = false;
    $(this).find('.required').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            errors = true;
        }
    });
    if (errors == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Hpe9/1/)

Comment: can you create a fiddle? Code seems alright to me.

Comment: Create jsfiddle please

Comment: @PratikJoshi Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Hpe9/1/

Comment: what do you mean by checking the "error" variable?

Comment: The code seems to work perfectly for me.

Comment: @Raver0124 if a field is not filled in correctly, the errors variable get set to true. If is is true, the submit button should not submitten.

Comment: @Scimonster You are right! My code works. Stupid me.. I did some extra php checking in the real website and that was giving me the idea that the code not worked correctly.

Comment: But I started a bounty, but I cannot give anyone the reputation. What should I do now? And how can I set the question to solved now?

Comment: You can post an answer and accept it to show that you've solved it. Sorry about the bounty though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my code just works. The reason I thought it was not working, is because I was still using PHP handling my real website where I made 1 field required and in my jQuery not. This made the confusion.

So the following code works:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function (event) {
    var errors = false;
    $(this).find('.required').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            errors = true;
        }
    });
    if (errors == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code should do what you want, just give your contact form submit button the id of `#contact-form-button`.

```
$('#contact-form-button').click(function(e) {  // using click function
                                               // on contact form submit button
    e.preventDefault();  // stop form from submitting right away

    var error = false;

    $(this).find('.required').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            error = true;
        }
    });

    if (!error) {                     // if not any errors
        $('#contact-form').submit();  // you submit form
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function (event) {
    var errors = false;
    $(this).find('.required').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            errors = true;
        }
    });
    if (errors == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
})
```

if validation cross successfully then it return true for submit the form